# Check to see if two lists have the same value at the same index, if so return the index. If not return -1

Tags: python, list, indexing, comparison

So basically I am trying to compare two lists to see if they hold the same value at the same index at any point. If they do I return the index, if they do not, I return -1.

When I had first done this as a test I was having no issues however adding in the text has made it more difficult and my main issue is with the if else statement. I seem to be able to only get one message to work, either yes or no, not both based on the case.

Comment: You print `No` **for every element that's not the same**. Don't do this in the loop

Comment: You set `found = True` so `if found == True` is **always** going to be true. Note that `if found` is the same as `if found == True`, no need to do the work `if` is doing, twice.

Comment: Finally, you already know how to `return`, returning is not the same as printing. If you have the answer, return the index. When you run out of elements (the loop completes), return `-1`. at the end of the function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you think you could whip up some example code if it wouldn't be too much trouble? I learn best by analyzing code and breaking it down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a cleaner answer uses the built-in `enumerate` and `zip` functions:

```py
Dlist = [17,13,10,6,2]
Ilist = [5,9,10,15,18]

def seqsearch(DS,IS):
    for idx, (d, s) in enumerate(zip(DS, IS)):
        if d == s:
            return f"Yes! Found at index = {idx}"

    return "No!\n-1"


print(seqsearch(Dlist,Ilist))
```

It's unclear whether you want to return just the first index, or all the indices with matching elements. In either case, it is probably better if you just return the desired value and then add any formatting and print statements outside of the function's scope.

Comment: The task is to return the index or `-1`, not a string. Have the function return *machine readable information*, only print once the task is complete. The function can then be used for other purposes too.

Comment: It's better to use `return idx` and `return -1`, then use `index = seqsearch(...)` and use `if` statements to print something human readable.

Comment: Yes I agree, I was just keeping the return output the same for OP

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over both lists like so:

```
Dlist = [17, 13, 10, 6, 2]
Ilist = [5, 9, 10, 15, 18]


def seqsearch(DS, IS):

    for index_1, element_1 in enumerate(DS):
        for index_2, element_2 in enumerate(IS):

            if (element_1 == element_2) and (index_1 == index_2):
                print(f"Yes! Found at index ={index_1}")
                return index_1
    print("No!")
    return -1


print(seqsearch(Dlist, Ilist))
```

However, there are more improvements you can make. `zip()` indeed is a better option, but slightly more complicated to understand.

Also, please note that `return` is not the same as `print`. You were *not* returning `-1`; you were printing it.

Answer (score -1):

i try use your code for better undrestand (but based of your use we have many option)

```
Dlist = [17, 13, 10, 6, 2]
Ilist = [5, 9, 10, 15, 18]


def seqsearch_with_print(DS, IS):
    """this function only print not return!!!
    if you use return your function ended!"""
    for i in range(len(DS) - 1):
        if DS[i] == IS[i]:
            print(f"Yes! Found at index {i}")
        else:
            print(f"No not equal in {i} index")


def seqsearch_with_list(DS, IS):
    """this function save history of (equal index or not: as 1, -1)"""
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(len(DS) - 1):
        if DS[i] == IS[i]:
            temp_list.append(1)
        else:
            temp_list.append(-1)
    return temp_list


def seqsearch_with_list_dict(DS, IS):
    """this function save history of (equal index or not: as 1, -1)
    as key, value (key== index, value==list item)"""
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(len(DS) - 1):
        if DS[i] == IS[i]:
            temp_list.append({i: 1})
        else:
            temp_list.append({i: -1})
    return temp_list


# no need print(in function we used print)
seqsearch_with_print(Dlist, Ilist)
"""
return of function: 
    No not equal in 0 index
    No not equal in 1 index
    Yes! Found at index 2
    No not equal in 3 index"""

# save history of search index in list
print(seqsearch_with_list(Dlist, Ilist))
"""
return of function with print:
    [-1, -1, 1, -1]
"""
# save history as dict key value
print(seqsearch_with_list_dict(Dlist, Ilist))
"""
return of function with print
    [{0: -1}, {1: -1}, {2: 1}, {3: -1}]
"""
```